# What are textured ceilings made out of?

Tags: ceiling, asbestos

This is a single family home built in 2015 in the Midwest. The textured ceiling you see below seems common around the area, even in newer homes. I'm curious what material it's made out of (drywall mud?) and whether it may contain asbestos. I heard old popcorn ceilings can contain asbestos and even though this one is not popcorn it may still use similar material.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do knockdown texture walls usually contain asbestos?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/285886/do-knockdown-texture-walls-usually-contain-asbestos)

Comment: Sugar, and spice, and everything nice. Oh, wait, sorry...

Comment: I've had enough problems with pests *without* a ceiling made of sugar and spice. I guess that's why gingerbread houses never really caught on.

Comment: 2015 construction would not have contained asbestos.

Answer (score 3):

> *built in 2015*

According to [this lawyer's page](https://www.lanierlawfirm.com/mesothelioma/asbestos-exposure/products/drywall/), the CPSC banned asbestos in drywall compound in 1977, but old stock could have lasted several years. Almost certainly by 2015 any new construction would be using new materials that are asbestos-free. There are other reasons not to worry too much about asbestos, but the odds of you having any in a 2015 home are very, very small.

That being said, here is some more general guidance:

- Asbestos (big concern) and lead paint (also a big concern, but for different reasons, but also very unlikely in a 2015 home) are primarily concerns when disturbed. That includes cutting, sanding and similar activities. Covered up and/or out of reach of children (like a ceiling) there really is nothing to be concerned about.
- Activities that generate lots of dust - cutting, sanding and similar activities - are a concern even if you *don't* have asbestos or lead. Even though many other materials won't cause cancer (asbestos) or brain damage (lead), they can still be major irritants to eyes, lungs, etc. So if you are doing any significant cutting, sanding, etc. then eye protection (goggles) and a good mask are important. Note that a typical COVID-19 10 cent "surgical mask" only provides minimal protection, though certainly better than nothing. Look for N95 as one useful specification, and also look for masks/respirators designed for particular activities. Any big box home improvement store (Home Depot, Lowes, etc.) or decent hardware store should have plenty of options.

Comment: do you know if the ban applies to imported drywall compound too? (not sure how often builders in the US uses imported drywall compound...)

Comment: I am reasonably certain the ban applied to imported as well, as the concern here is not "production not good for the environment", where in some cases foreign products get a pass, but rather "**use** not good for people". Would certain Asian countries likely try to circumvent any such ban if they could get away with it? Of course. But I really **highly** doubt it by 2015 - that's decades past the ban. High-weight materials like drywall compound tend to be more likely to *not* be shipped halfway around the world, though there may be exceptions. But 2015 build? I really, really wouldn't worry.